# What is the best way to monitor a folder and dynamically symlink items into a different folder?

Tags: shell-script, symlink, monitoring, inotify

I have a second hard drive which has the following structure:

```bash
$ tree -L 1
.
├── Documents
├── Music
├── Pictures
└── Videos
```

I want to monitor these folders for changes and, if any, create a symlink of the new element (be it file or folder) into the appropriate folder in `/home`. Does anyone know if there are any existing tools for this already or should I just resort to creating a shell script and make use of something like good old `inotify-tools`?

If anyone has other clever suggestions I'm all ears.

Comment: If Linux, `inotify` should be able to do something. Not sure where else it is available.

Comment: I forgot to mention it but, yes, I'm using Linux. So you think `inotify` is the way to go?

Comment: It can certainly watch a set of directories for changes: do `man inotifywait` and see where it takes you.

Answer (score 1):

I find [incron](https://github.com/ar-/incron) a very useful tool for this type of thing. It has some bugs and at the time of writing has not being maintained for some years but there are patches if you need them. It allows you to create incrontab file(s) which are like crontabs but react to specified file or directory events.

Comment: Interesting. Where can these patches be found?

Comment: see the pull requests in the Github repository. I use it (v0.5.12) unpatched.